# Last array printing 0 C++

Tags: c++, arrays, ubuntu

I'm making a dice game in C++, and in my program I have some arrays.

```
die[5] = { (rand()%6)+1, (rand()%6)+1, (rand()%6)+1, (rand()%6)+1, (rand()%6)+1 };
```

And then I use the arrays with

```
cout<<"First die: "<< die[0] <<"\n"
```

etc

But, when I run the program, the last array will *always* print 0, is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: By "last array", do you mean die[4]?

Comment: Oh, sorry.  Forgot to post a link to the source code.  Here it is: http://pastebin.com/etUqt43U

Comment: @Gaminic       No, I meant die[5]

Comment: That's what I thought. Check my Answer below. Short version: there is no die[5]. There is die[0] to die[4], a total of 5 elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you have this line:

```
54.  cout<<"Sixth die: " << die[5] <<"\n";
```

which is an invalid access as die has only 5 elements thus 0 to 4 are valid indexes.

This is actually "undefined behaviour". Your program might core-dump / give an access violation but it doesn't have to. It can instead just output some random number or zero...

Answer (score 6):

You're not really giving much information, but here's my guess:

- You're stepping too far. The last spot in the array is die[4], and chances are you're using die[5], which means you're accessing memory you're not supposed to. On some systems, this will automatically initialize as "0".

Arrays of size N always include N elements ranging from 0 to N-1. Using array[N] accesses memory *beyond* the range of the array. This could be unused memory (best case) or memory assigned to something else. The result is TROUBLE. Do not do this.

Comment: Ok, I was able to fix it by changing die[5] to die[6] and adding another element.  Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! Little tip: if you explicitly define a variable with the array-size ("N") it's much easier to spot out-of-bounds problems. In loops, you'll always go "i < N". You can manually check "i >= N" for bad access indexes and all of that. Make it explicit!